# PHP wrong timezone mail

Tags: php, email, timezone

My PHP mail is sent with a wrong date & time.
I've set my PHP time:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
```

and when I

```
echo date('r'); //returns correctly: Thu, 02 Aug 2012 13:28:00
```

I get the correct time. When I send a mail however, the date of the mail is the time now + 1 day + 1 hour.

I've searched around and found some old docs where it was a PHP bug or so, but those date from 2001 and 2005 so I presume I'm doing someting else wrong... I expect theres no error in the sending of the mail, since it does get sent, but I'll post my code anyway:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
    $receiver = 'test@yourhost.com';
    $subject = 'Test';
    $message = 'This is a test';
    $receiver = $email;
    $headers = "From: me@myhost.com" . "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
    if(mail($receiver,$subject,$message,$headers)){
        //This is done
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this :-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

or

try this

```
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/New_York' );
```

//or

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

Comment: Read it - I assume the mail function uses date.timezone from the .ini ? Though I don't quite see how I can fix it...

Comment: i have update my answer please take a look ini_set function use in your php file.Please take a look and let me know if it is working.

Comment: Using ini_set('date.timezon','Europe/Brussels');, it works fine, thanks a lot! Now I just have to figure out how to set it in the .htaccess, then I don't have to set it on each page, and I don't have access to the php.ini

Comment: you can set below value in .htaccess                           php_value date.timezone "Europe/Vilnius"

Comment: Yes indeed I had just found it and it works splendid. Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't understand this answer because the question includes code that clearly has use of date_default_timezone_set() and the accepted answer is simply a post to a url about date_default_timezone_set()

Answer (score 3):

This is a misconfiguration of your php.ini
in your php.ini, search:

```
; date.timezone
```

replace whit:

```
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

and restart apache

List of Supported Timezones:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

**Edit:** in htaccess, the timezone should be used in this way:

```
php_value date.timezone "Europe/Brussels"
```

Comment: Thanks, don't have access to the php.ini though since it's a shared server, but I'll try and set it in te .htaccess

Comment: in htaccess, the timezone should be used in this way:     
`php_value date.timezone "Europe/Brussels"` (first post edited)